# Problems creating a CustomToast with react-native-toast-message

Tags: react-native

I have a problem creating a custom Toast-message for my react-native project.

I want to adjust just some styles e.g. the text-color and the height.
For this reason I have tried multiple things:

1. https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/main/docs/custom-layouts.md => I used the tutorial/documentation to create a custom layout - this file is stored in `./components/CustomToast`

```
// App.jsx
import Toast, { BaseToast, ErrorToast } from 'react-native-toast-message';

/*
  1. Create the config
*/
const toastConfig = {
  /*
    Overwrite 'success' type,
    by modifying the existing `BaseToast` component
  */
  success: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      style={{ borderLeftColor: 'pink' }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: '400'
      }}
    />
  ),

  /*
    Overwrite 'success' type,
    by modifying the existing `BaseToast` component
  */
  customError: (props) => (
    <ErrorToast
      {...props}
      style={{ borderLeftColor: 'pink', color: "red" }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 15,
        color: "red",
        fontWeight: '400'
      }}
    />
  ),
  /*
    Overwrite 'error' type,
    by modifying the existing `ErrorToast` component
  */
  error: (props) => (
    <ErrorToast
      {...props}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 17
      }}
      text2Style={{
        fontSize: 15
      }}
    />
  ),
  /*
    Or create a completely new type - `tomatoToast`,
    building the layout from scratch.

    I can consume any custom `props` I want.
    They will be passed when calling the `show` method (see below)
  */
  CustomToast: ({ text1, props }) => (
    <View style={{ height: 60, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}>
      <Text>{text1}</Text>
      <Text>{props.uuid}</Text>
    </View>
  )
};

/*
  2. Pass the config as prop to the Toast component instance
*/
export function App(props) {
  return (
      <Toast config={toastConfig} />
  );
}
```

2. I loaded the code into my project:

```
import Toast, { BaseToast, ErrorToast }  from "react-native-toast-message";
import CustomToast from '../components/CustomToast'; // Adjust the path to CustomToast

import standardStyles from "../styles/standardStyles";
import { scale, verticalScale } from "./scale";

function customErrorToast(message) {

  Toast.show({
    type: 'CustomToast',
    config: {CustomToast},
    autoHide: false,
    autoHideTime: 9000,
    topOffset: 50,
    text1: 'Fehler',
    text2: message ? message : 'Etwas ist schief gelaufen',
  props: { uuid: 'bba1a7d0-6ab2-4a0a-a76e-ebbe05ae6d70' }
  });

}

function customSuccessToast(message) {
  Toast.show({
    type: 'success',
    config: {CustomToast},
    autoHide: false,
    autoHideTime: 9000,
    topOffset: 50,
    text1: 'Erfolg',
    text2: message ? message : 'Erfolgreich übertragen',
    customComponent: CustomToast,
  });

}
```

Resulting in the error:

```
 ERROR  Error: Toast type: 'CustomToast' does not exist. You can add it via the 'config' prop on the Toast instance. Learn more: https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/master/README.md

This error is located at:
    in ToastUI
    in Unknown (created by Toast)
    in LoggerProvider (created by Toast)
    in Toast (created by App)
    in PersistGate (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
    in QueryClientProvider (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in MyProjectApp(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

The second try was to skip the CustomToast-File and try to load the Toast-config directly:

```
import Toast, { BaseToast, ErrorToast }  from "react-native-toast-message";

import standardStyles from "../styles/standardStyles";
import { scale, verticalScale } from "./scale";

const toastConfig = {

  /*
    Overwrite 'success' type,
    by modifying the existing `BaseToast` component
  */
  success: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      style={{ borderLeftColor: 'pink', color: "red"  }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        color: "red",
      }}
      text2Style={{
        color: "red",
      }}
    />
  ),

  /*
    Custom customError type,
    by modifying the existing `BaseToast` component
  */
  customError: (props) => (
    <ErrorToast
      {...props}
      style={{ borderLeftColor: 'pink', color: "red" }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        color: "red",
      }}
      text2Style={{
        color: "red",
      }}
    />
  ),
  /*
    Overwrite 'error' type,
    by modifying the existing `ErrorToast` component
  */
  error: (props) => (
    <ErrorToast
      {...props}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 17,
        color: "red",
      }}
      text2Style={{
        fontSize: 15,
        color: "red",
      }}
    />
  ),
  /*
    Or create a completely new type - `tomatoToast`,
    building the layout from scratch.

    I can consume any custom `props` I want.
    They will be passed when calling the `show` method (see below)
  */
  CustomToast: ({ text1, props }) => (
    <View style={{ height: 60, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}>
      <Text>{text1}</Text>
      <Text>{props.uuid}</Text>
    </View>
  )
};
function customErrorToast(message) {

  Toast.show({
    type: 'CustomToast',
    config: {toastConfig},
    autoHide: false,
    autoHideTime: 9000,
    topOffset: 50,
    text1: 'Fehler',
    text2: message ? message : 'Etwas ist schief gelaufen',
  props: { uuid: 'bba1a7d0-6ab2-4a0a-a76e-ebbe05ae6d70' }
  });

}

function customSuccessToast(message) {
  Toast.show({
    type: 'success',
    config: {toastConfig},
    autoHide: false,
    autoHideTime: 9000,
    topOffset: 50,
    text1: 'Erfolg',
    text2: message ? message : 'Erfolgreich übertragen',
    customComponent: CustomToast,
  });

}
```

With the very same error. (Even if I use type: 'success' - The changes of my config will not be active.

My question is what is my mistake?
I even asked ChatGPT -but it could not help either :D

Best regards

I want to adjust the height of the Toast so it adjusts to the content - right now the text overflows the container and is unreadable. I also want a slight red Background.

I would be grateful to see my mistake